# Django: Accented characters in settings.py are broken when accessed in a view

Tags: django, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I have accented characters in my settings.py that I access in a view using getattr(settings, 'MY_CONSTANT_NAME', []) but the getattr() call return broken characters (for example, "ô" become: "\xc3\xb4").

here is the code in view.py:

```
    from django.conf import settings

    def getValueFromSetting(request):
        mimetype = 'application/json' 
        charset=utf-8' datasources = getattr(settings, 'MY_CONSTANT_NAME', []) 
        config= '{' 
        config+= '"datasources": ' + str(datasources).replace("'", '"') 
        config+= '}'

        return HttpResponse(config,mimetype)
```

What I have done so far to try to solve the problem:

- I put # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- as the first line of my settings.py and my views.py
- I put u'ô' or unicode('ô') in front of special characters in settings.py
- I put DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8' in settings.py
- I try all possible combination of .decode('utf-8'), .encode('utf-8'), .decode('iso-8859-1'), .encode('iso-8859-1') on the special characters in settings.py or in the views.py...

Nothing solve the problem.

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Thank you

Etienne

Comment: So exactly where are you seeing this "broken" output? In fact that looks completely correct to me, but never mind. How are you outputting this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're seeing these `\xc3\xb4` strings in your browser.. Have you tried editing your template file to define the proper charset in the HTML header?

```
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="example" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="something" />
  <meta name="author" content="Etienne" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />      <!--  <---- This line -->
</head>
```

**Edit after your first comment in this answer:**

I suspect `getattr` will not work with other than `ascii` encoding. Do you think something like the following will not do what you want?

```
from django.conf import settings

def getValueFromSetting(request):
    myConstantValue = settings.MY_CONSTANT_NAME
    # check myConstantValue here
```

**Edit after last comments:**

I think now I understand your problem. You don't like the fact that the JSON returned by the view is ASCII-only. I recommend you to use `dumps` function provided by the `json` module bundled with Python. Here's an example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# other required imports here
import json

def dumpjson(request):
   response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(settings.CONSTANT_TUPLE, encoding='utf-8', ensure_ascii=False), content_type='application/json')

   return response
```

The `CONSTANT_TUPLE` in the example is just a copy of `DATABASES` in my `settings.py`.

The important bit here is `ensure_ascii=False`. Could you try it? Is that what you want?

Comment: I saw these strings before sending it to browser... I saw it directly in my view when debugging (In Aptana Studio)... I also saw the same behaviour in my browser even having put <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> in the web page <head>

Comment: I just try it and I have the same charset problem using myConstantValue = settings.MY_CONSTANT_NAME instead of calling getattr...

Comment: can you show a bit more of your code? What are you doing with `myConstantValue` in that view? What about the template?

Comment: My goal is to  get this constant from settings.py and return it in JSON format to an Ajax call from Javascript. The constant contain a list of dictionnaries.

Comment: It will be way easier to read if you update the code block in your original question.

Comment: Using json.dumps as you suggested solve the problem... Thanks a lot!