# UTF8 and JSON in Flask

Tags: python, json, unicode, utf-8, flask

In `Flask/Python` We have a dictionary like this created by the `json.loads` function:

```
{ "msg": [
        "Dobr\u00fd den."
      ] }
```

We return a JSON response from our HTTP GET web method like `return flask.jsonify(**myjson)`. But even the web browser is configured to use `UTF-8` what we see is `Dobr\u00fd den.` and not `Dobrý den.` (what we want, i.e. decoded UTF8 character). Please, how to achieve that?

Comment: [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767520/django-accented-characters-in-settings-py-are-broken-when-accessed-in-a-view/10767606#10767606) a solution I posted to a similar issue with django. But I still think there's nothing wrong with utf represented in ascii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try encoding the response to utf-8.